# What does 'spatio pollicarir emotius' mean in Otto von Guericke's Experimenta Nova?

Tags: vocabulary, new-latin, science

In Otto von Guericke's *Experimenta Nova* (1672) he says (in reference to experiments showing how a feather floats above and sometimes is reattracted to a globe of sulphur):

> 5. Filum lineum, si acumini ligni acuminati, inque mensâ vel scamno firmati inhærescere facias, atque filum ulnâ longius demittas, ita quidem, ut infra ibi aliud quid, **spatio pollicarir emotius**, attingere possit, (Quoties scil. globus excitatus, summitati hujus ligni admoveatur) inferius fili cum iuxta apposito, conjungi: Quo ad oculos demonstrandum, hanc virtutem in filo lineo usque ad partes infimas se extendisse, dum hoc, aut attrahit aut seipsum alligat.

[Source](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/60116#page/179/mode/1up). (Emphasis mine.)

I believe *emotius* is the comparison form of ēmōtus (ppl from ēmōvēre), and since ulna is nearby, I thought pollicarir might be related to pollex (thumb), but I couldn't find another usage. What does this part of the paragraph mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe *pollicarir* to be a typographical error, as *spatio pollicari* (from *pollicaris*) would mean "by a thumbsbreadth." This exact collocation isn't classical, as far as I can tell, but seems quite in keeping with the several versions found in Pliny: *pollicari crassitudine*, *pollicari latitudine*, *pollicari amplitudine*.

As for *emotius*, that could be another error, as *emotus* by itself is intelligible, or maybe even *remotius* (?), but I do think it's possible that a neo-Latin writer might treat *emotus* as an adjective from which a comparative could be formed.

Comment: To summarise your answer - spatio pollicarir emotius makes no sense, moving the “r” to just after the space makes *spatio pollicari remotius* which makes perfect sense.